# Text align by word length

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, arraylist

I have been working on a project that has a similar result as the spritz app. Basically, it takes a string, turns each word into an array and then displays each output one at a time. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to align each word based on the word length (see link).

Here is a demo of the spritz output that I am looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLGzD.jpg

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to center an output based on the the length of a word?

IE:
If array length is 1 letter, center letter
If array length is 2 - 4, center second letter
if array length is 5 - 7, center third letter
ect.

Comment: What have *you* tried to accomplish this?

Comment: I have been fooling around with tables and printing the output in separate tables based on word length in order to create some sort of alignment. But, it's not a very friendly solution. This is my second week learning JS (or any language), so my knowledge is limited.

Comment: And for some solidarity, I taught myself everything I know, and still I almost only ever come to stack exchange to *ask* questions, haha. go team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start that might could work for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/ap64C/

Use an element to measure width. Calculate width of word to middle w/wo center letter.

For example having the element:

```
<span id="tw"></span>
```

and CSS:

```
#tw { 
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    font: bold 18px Arial;
}
```

One can:

```
// get element
tw = document.getElementById('tw');
// set text
tw.textContent = 'foo';
// get width
tw.offsetWidth;
```

Having this as base we can split word into three groups:

1. Letters belonging to the left of center letter.
2. Letters for left + center.
3. Letters after center.

Example. Having the word `starting` and a box where we want to center at offset 110 pixels from left.

```
length = 8
left   = sta
center = r
right  = ting

width_left = 15
width_left + width_center = 19

mid = (19 - 15) / 2

box margin left = 110 - (width_left + mid)
```

Simple, *should be refactored code*, sample:

```
// span's for left, center and right
var tx = {
    L: document.getElementById('txt_L'),
    C: document.getElementById('txt_C'),
    R: document.getElementById('txt_R')
};
// Box to that holds span's, to set margin left on.
var b = document.getElementById('bw');

function width(w) {
    tw.textContent = w;
    return tw.offsetWidth;
}
function middle(w) {
    var n = w.length,
        // Center char calculation. 1=1, 2-5=2, 6-8=3, ...
        c = ~~((n + 1) / 3) + 1,
        z = {};
    z.a = width(w.substr(0, c - 1));
    z.b = width(w.substr(0, c));
    z.c = (z.b - z.a) / 2;
    b.style.marginLeft = ~~(110 - (z.a + z.c)) + 'px';

    tx.L.textContent = w.substr(0, c - 1);
    tx.C.textContent = w.substr(c - 1, 1);
    tx.R.textContent = w.substr(c);
}
```

Comment: In all seriousness, that is the most impressive thing I have seen in a long time. I am going to be up all night picking this apart this code to understand the intricacies that went into making it work. It looks like I was dead on with the set interval/ wpm piece, but the split into three groups was a great idea. I can simply just plug in the code I already wrote for the text and wpm selection and this should be good to go! You are my hero.

Comment: @Jon: Good to hear it was useful :). Fun project. The code needs refactoring and sorry for my variable names etc. which are not the most descriptive, but hope you manage to read it. And yes, the wpm was bulls eye. `setInterval` does not guarantee a delay, but in code like this one should not notice the discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Background On Your Problem**

I believe you're going to find this either very difficult to solve or else are going to have to railroad you users quite dramatically.

Words don't have lengths, because characters aren't all of the same size, and even the space between letters is different The exception is of course monospaced fonts (and they aren't really an exception they just behave like one).

To achieve what you're after, you need to know the precise size of each letter, and for real accuracy would need to know the precise size of each letter *in relation to it's adjacent letters*. But that's typography nitty-gritty and probably not what you want to do.

If it were me, I'd artificially do it with

tags, whose width you could specify (say, your largest character + 1 px). Then word length will always be equivalent to some multiple of the parent element.

The other option would be to render the text as image via HTML5 canvas, which could be made to autofit the word and then would have, itself, a width property.

**A Solution to Consider**

Try something like:

```
<style>
li.char {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:4px;
}
li.char.center { color:red}
</style>
<body>
```

...

```
<div style="text-align:center">
 <ul id="spritztext"> </ul>
</div>
<script>
var my_string = "strings are cool";
var center = ceil( my_string.len() / 2); 
/* rounding up/down is a bad solution to finding the center character, for what it's worth. examine the words 'will' vis 'limb' in a proportional font and you'll see why*/
var count = 0;
$(my_string).each(function() {
   var class = count == center ? "char center" : "char"; 
    count++
    var char_element ="<li class='" + class +"'>" + my_string[count] + "</li>";
    $("#spritztext").append(char_element)
});
```

TLDR: text isn't graphics; you need a monospaced font, a rendering strategy, or a hack via parent elements

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer and taking the time to explain the best strategies. I will be using courier new (a monospaced font) until I find a more style friendly monospaced font. 

Assuming that I use a monospaced font, is there a simpler way to go about this? Here is a link to what i've put together thus far http://jsfiddle.net/Adrenaline981/xn2L3/3/

Comment: The thing about using a monospaced font is that you can't actually guarantee your use won't prefer a different font, or have their text scaled up—you'll have to know how big a character is in order to do the math. Wrapping your characters in an element will depend on less hail-mary calculating and give you more control over flexible presentation. :) (PS I didn't run what I wrote above, be wary of typos, haha)

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing. I am going to try and get it to work with my current code. About finding the center character; spritz doesn't always seem to center based on the median letter of the text. It seems to follow a set of rules.

Comment: Yeah, I am very sure Sprtiz does what you've intended to do; the difference is that I don't think you can appreciate how  much work that is. Take a peak at the wikipedia entry on kerning & ligatures and the difference between pt (points) and px, and finally what an "em" and an "en" are, you'll get the idea. If you want it to be dead center, there's just no escaping doing the typographic math. : |

Comment: I had no clue that it was this intense under the hood. Thank you for opening my eyes to the complexity of text. I wish there was some way to award you reddit gold or a prize for this haha. Even though I am still trying to mesh this with my own code (unsuccessfully, because i'm am a complete beginner), I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Hey guy, while I think I had you on the right track with wrapping  your characters, @supNate's idea is better than mine by a lot. span tags are inline, and the width you'd get from the offSetWidth is a really smart way of getting the char widths as they're rendered by the browser.

Comment: (oh and dude you're so welcome; go see my user page and see my questions asked vs answers given, haha. I got some cray help when I first got here, happy to give a lil back)

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be divide the word into two parts and use a table-like two column layout to show the word. Like this:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 200px;"><tr>
  <td style="text-align: right; width: 100px; padding: 0;">wo</td>
  <td style="text-align: left; width: 100px; padding: 0;">rd</td>
</tr></table>
```

This doesn't exactly align a letter center at one position, but could align left or right edge of a letter exactly at some position.

To refine the solution, you may need to get letter/character width on demand (By creating a temp 'span' node with inner text of the letter, then get the offsetWidth). Then adjust the margin of the two parts to achieve the exactly goal.

Comment: yea, this is definitely a cool solution to the problem. Now, time to find out how to divide the arrays in half haha. Thank you!